# REGEX to get ID ath the end of an URL without /

Tags: javascript, regex, greasemonkey

I'm trying to do a GreaseMonkey script and i'm stucked on a REGEX to get the ID of an article in URL.

I have URL like https://www.blabla.com/poney-2000-poneys-dance-bla,272317

And i want to use the ID at the end after the Comma : 272317

I tried this REGEX : (,([\d]+)) to avoid taking digit in the rest of the URL and it get me ,272317 but I want it without the comma at the begining.

Do you have an idea how i can improve my REGEX ?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative approach without regex:

```
var url = 'https://www.blabla.com/poney-2000-poneys-dance-bla,272317';
url.substring(url.lastIndexOf(',') + 1);
```

The regex would be `(\d+)$` to lookup the digits in the end but it doesn't consider the comma.

Answer (score 1):

Just need to remove that outer paran since you don't want to capture the ,

```
,(\d+)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `(?!,)([0-9]+){5}`, it should be fine as long as the id is greater than 5